# Correcting for heteroskedasticity in Logit fixed-effects model

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model

I found out that my panel data 'suffers' from heteroscedasticity by doing the test described  on Stata FAQ, [Testing for panel-level heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/panel-level-heteroskedasticity-and-autocorrelation/). I understand that the $H_0$ for `lrtest` is homoskedasticity and I'm rejecting this. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

I'm carrying out a fixed effects logistic regression with `xtlogit` and I found that the `vce` option should be used to correct for heteroskedasticity. Still, I don't understand when to use   `vce(bootstrap)` or `vce(jackknife)` ?

What's the difference between the two? How can I decide which one to use?

EDIT:
Some info on the data size:

```
   Number of observations: 116304
   Number of groups 2549
   Obs per group: min = 1
                  avg = 45.6273
                  max = 20
```

Comment: Aren't logit models heteroscedastic by definition? You explicitly model the mean-variance relationship through the logit link and binomial variance function.

Comment: The FAQ you link to seems to refer to linear models, and you have a non-linear (logit) model. So, I don't think the test is relevant.

Comment: Thanks! I just found your explanation for heteroscedasticity in probit models here @MaartenBuis : http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-11/msg00996.html

Comment: For clarification, does this mean that I don't worry about autocorrelation as well?